# JavaScript Append

Tags: javascript

I'm totally new in coding so if I may have some stupid code here.

I want to create a gallery with API and JavaScript. To have 10 images loaded from API and when we click on each of the pictures, the bigger version shows up besides it. I already have the API working with loading the picture but once I click on them, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>EX-4</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: arial;
    }
    
    #content {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    .bodyblue {
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .fullImage {
      position: absolute;
      top: 140px;
      width: 550px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 20px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      display: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body onload="buildImage();">

  <div class="contents" id="content"></div>
  <button onclick="changeImage();fullScreen();">Full screen</button>


  <div class="fullImage" id="fullImage">
    <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
  </div>

  <script>
    var images = [
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random',
    ];
    var index = 0;

    var timeOut;

    function buildImage() {
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
    }

    function changeImage() {
      index++;
      if (index >= images.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + (index + 1) + ')';
    }

    function fullScreen() {
      document.getElementById('fullImage').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see no click event on the div that holds the image....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored a couple of things, but here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/g6rfwohb/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    EX-4
  </title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: arial;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #content {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    .bodyblue {
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .fullImage {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    h1 {
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contents" id="content"></div>
  <p>
    <button id="fullscreenButton">Full screen</button>
  </p>
  <div class="fullImage" id="fullImage"></div>
  <script>
    var images = [
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=1',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=2',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=3',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=4',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=5',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=6',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=7',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=8',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=9',
      'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=10'
    ];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var full = document.getElementById('fullImage');
    var fullButton = document.getElementById('fullscreenButton');

    content.addEventListener('click', function() {
      currentIndex = currentIndex >= images.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
      content.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[currentIndex]})`;

    });

    fullButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      full.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[currentIndex]})`;

    });

    content.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[currentIndex]})`;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically, I removed the unneeded body `onload`. You have the `<script>` tag inside the body already, so code inside the script tag will run automatically. In my example, the content gets the first image in the array right off the bat.

I defined `content`, `full`, and `fullButton`, which are variable for the elements on the page. I then gave 'content' and `fullButton` click `eventListeners`. For 'content' just loops through the images and displays them. The `fullButton` sets the background image in the full container to the "full" size of the image.

In your initial code, you had the full div hidden with the CSS and the absolute positioning covered over the full image button.